# "Certificate Invalid" Error on my iPhone App

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode, swift

I just got done writing a program that will allow the creation and sign up of users. However, I keep getting this error after entering my information and hitting sign up: "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connection to a server that is pretending to be "domain-name" which could put your confidential information at risk.

I have domain and hosting services through Go Daddy, for a test environment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Swift for the app, and PHP and MySQL on the server side.

Comment: Is the certificate for the server you are connecting to valid? What happens when you visit the server in your browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just had to put my url as http and not https.